# Event triggered by condition

Tags: anylogic

I inserted a condition in the event window , this conditions refers to a variable in  my main agent. I dont't understand why the condition is not evaluated by the event . I searched on the help and it suggest to use the onChange function , but i can't understand where and how to use it.
Thanks

Comment: It is generally advisable to stay clear of condition-triggered events and statechart transitions. They are intuitive to understand but can be a pain to ensure they work. And very hard to debug. Luckily, you can *always* reformulate the problem using messages or similar.

Comment: Thank you Benjamin !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The onChange is used to make sure the condition is evaluated when it needs to in case AnyLogic missed it, since AnyLogic does not evaluate the conditions every moment in time, instead, it just evaluates them at important time steps.

So, where to put onChange() depends on what your condition is. For example, if you condition is having a queue length of say 10, then I would add the onChange() function on the "On Enter" and "On Exit" of the queue, so that each time an agent enters or leaves the queue, the condition is evaluated.

So again, where to use onChange depends on what your condition is. If this doesn't help, feel free to provide more details on what your condition is.

Comment: Thank you  !! I ' ve decided to avoid the event triggered by condition , I' ve used other tools to achieve the same purpose.